# How to manage scroll in combobox

Tags: .net, winforms

How can I manage scroll in WinForms' combo box dropdown list? For now, it is at the bottom after opening it (as I understand it's just a coincidence - my combo box behavior is default). Is there any way how to get scroll at the top after opening the list and save selection?
Here are 2 screenshots: how it looks now and what I would like to get:

[image: Now]
[image: I want to get]

Comment: That's not the default behavior.  If nothing is selected from the list, the scroll will start at the top.  If something is selected, the combo box will make sure the highlighted item is visible on the screen.

Comment: I think it's just a coincidence. Its current behavior is a default now.

Comment: No, that's not the default behavior.  Post code that will duplicate the problem.